# Add three objects to STL list

Tags: c++, list, class, stl

I have a template class that has three data members: “val1”, “val2”, and “val3”. I would like to define in the main function, an STL list structure of the template class. I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to add three objects to the list, and then I will print them out while retrieving the list.

This line produces an error:    singleTemplate t(8, 5, 6);

Error   C2664

> No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

**Implementation:**

```
#pragma once

template < class T1, class T2, class T3 >

class singleTemplate
{
public:
    singleTemplate();
    singleTemplate(T1 v1, T2 v2, T3 v3);
    void setVal(T1 v1, T2 v2, T3 v3);
    void show();
private:
    T1 val1;
    T2 val2;
    T3 val3;
};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "singleTemplate.h"
#include <forward_list>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{

    forward_list<double> mylist;

    singleTemplate t(8, 5, 6);

    mylist.push_front(t);
}
```

Comment: "_This line produces an error:_" Please copy-paste the error you get. I don't know about you, but I don't memorize the error codes.

Comment: `t` is not a `double`.  `std::list` doesn't know how to insert it.  If you want it to expand to pushing `t`'s members then you need to write a function to do that for you.

Comment: You created a `forward_list` of `double` and then you try to `push_front` a `single_parameter` type variable. In a `list<T>` you can only `push` variable of type `T`. In your case, `double`.

Comment: In Visual Studio you can easily copy the text of the error message from the Output Tab. Please use that and not the errors list. And like@AlgirdasPreidžius I too have not memorized error code C2664

Comment: Sorry: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called,

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve here. Please [edit]  your question and elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you are trying to achive. Maybe you misunderstood the purpose of templates.

Maybe you want something like this:

```
#include <forward_list>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  forward_list<singleTemplate<int, int, double>> mylist;
  singleTemplate<int, int, double> t;
  mylist.push_front(t);
}
```

But for this to compile you need at least to implement a default constructor like this:

```
template < class T1, class T2, class T3 >    
class singleTemplate
{
public:
  singleTemplate() {};                  // <<< modify here
  singleTemplate(T1 v1, T2 v2, T3 v3);
  void setVal(T1 v1, T2 v2, T3 v3);
  void show();
private:
  T1 val1;
  T2 val2;
  T3 val3;
};
```

If you want to use the other constructor and the `setVal` and `show` methods you also need to implement them.